# Print singly linked list in reverse order

Tags: recursion, linked-list, nodes, reverse, iteration

Okay, this was the bonus question in CMPS 280's test at southeastern Louisiana Univ. Print singly linked list in reverse in three lines. Any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

C implementation of your bonus question, in three lines:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node* next;
};

void ReversePrint(struct node* head) {
    if(head == NULL) return;
    ReversePrint(head->next);
    printf("%d ", head->data);
}

int main()
{
    struct node first;
    struct node second;
    struct node third;

    first.data = 1;
    second.data = 2;
    third.data = 3;

    first.next = &second;
    second.next = &third;

    ReversePrint(&first); // Should print: 3 2 1
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first line of `ReversePrint` should be `if head == NULL`. Otherwise you will get a `SEGFAULT` if head is `NULL` and you check if `head->next` is `NULL`

Comment: By the way, you should also initialize memory for the `struct nodes` before attempting to add data to them.

Comment: `if(head == NULL) return;` can simply be written as `if (!head)return;`

Comment: Isn't it a bad idea to use recursion here? Since, the size of the node can be very large?

Answer (score 2):

Generally, when asking for help on SO, you should always try to do the problem yourself first. Then, if you are stuck, come here with what you have done so far and clearly show what your problem is to maximize your chances of getting help.

[How to ask a good question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

However, since it is a past exam question and my answer wont help you cheat :), here's pseudo-code how you can do it recursively:

```
reversePrint(head)
    if head is null then return // Line 1: base case
    reversePrint(head.next)     // Line 2: print the list after head
    print(head.data)            // Line 3: print head
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are allowed to use another Data Structure, then use a Stack.

Step 1: Traverse the linked list from the head node and put the key into the stack, till you reach the last node. This will take O(n) time.

Step 2 : Pop the elements out from the stack. This will take O(1) time.

Therefore, code will be

```
while(head != null){
stack.push(head.val);
head = head.next;
}
while(stack.isEmpty() != true){
stack.pop();
}
```

Comment: Step 2 will also take O(n). Good thing O(n) + O(n) is still just 2O(n) == O(n) though.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the different ways of doing it. Complete source code can be at found the hyperlinks below.

1) **Printing using extra memory** : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-reverse-linked-list-using-stack/

2) **Printing using recursion** : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-reverse-of-a-linked-list-without-actually-reversing/

3) **Printing by modifying original list** - i.e. first reverse the list and then print from start.

Source Code for reversing list : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reverse-a-linked-list/

4) **Printing without using extra space or modifying original list** : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-reverse-linked-list-without-extra-space-modifications/

5) **Printing using Carriage return (“r”)** : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/an-interesting-method-to-print-reverse-of-a-linked-list/

Answer (score 0):

Below is my iterative Java solution without stacks. I suppose the space complexity is still O(n) because the length of the `StringBuilder` grows linearly with the number of items in the list. However, we can get away without using a stack (either the data structure or the recursive call stack), neither of which is necessary if all we're doing is printing the elements to console. Also, the iterative stack solutions use two loops whereas this method only requires one. Finally, the time complexity is still O(n), which is much better than the quadratic algorithm by Geeks for Geeks referenced in another answer.

```
void printInReverse(ListNode head) {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

  ListNode n = head;
  while (n != null) {
    sb.insert(0, "<-" + n.data);
    n = n.next;
  }

  System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```